# axios - requests pool implementation

Tags: axios

I'm looking for a way to create a pool of HTTP requests and have a timer that will send them every `x` seconds.

I'm using `axios` as my HTTP client and wonder if there is a hook in `axios` to handle a request before it being sent, save it in this pool and resolve immediately, then my timer will do the actual request asynchronously.

I imagine to have some ability like that like that:

```
const pool = [];

setInterval(() => {
    const promises = [];
    while(pool.length){
        const { url, data, config } = pool.pop();

        delete config.usePool;

        // This request will be send to the server
        promises.push(axios.post(url, data, config);
    }

    await Promise.all(promises);
}, 5000);

// this `axios.hook` not really exists, im looking for a way to implement it (this is my actual question)
axios.hook = (url, data, config) => {
    if(config?.usePool){
        pool.push({ url, data, config });
    }
};

// This request won't send but save in the pool
const res = axios.post('/my/url', { a: 1, b: 1 }, { usePool: true });
```

Comment: Just being curious: what would be the purpose of sending them at fixed `x` second intervals?

Comment: It's just an illustration, basically my goal is to save the requests in the localStorage and fetch them from there. My use case is that sometimes i havea page reload before the request can fulfill and i don't want to lose it.

Comment: I tend to use [dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) server-side as a single source of truth data layer (with batching, de-duplication, caching). I'm not sure if it's a good fit for your use-case but it can be used client-side as well.

Comment: yeh, but i have to make this pool in the client-side, before it sends to the server

Comment: Yes I understood that. It can be used at client-side as well: https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/issues/101

Comment: thanks! saw it, the motivation of using it isn't so clear from the docs TBH :) also, it basically, I'm more looking for the easiest way to extend axios in the particular way I mentioned (a hook to catch the request before it sends and resolve the promise to the caller without really make the server call no, but later thru the pool)

Answer (score 0):

For a request pool of size `8`, you can use the following implementation:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { Agent } = require('https');

export default axios.create({
    httpsAgent: new Agent({
        maxSockets: 8
    })
});
```

You can find more configuration options for the https agent here:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions

There isn't an option available to space out the requests in time as you desired, although the usefulness of that approach is debatable.

Comment: With this syntax it exports an instance of the agent pool right? Similar to first defining it as a constant.

Comment: This answer does export an instance of an axios agent, yes. The code in the question uses the default agent, yes.